Can't comprehend how insets in Compose work. Why do I have this space here?
I am trying to learn about how Composables work, but it's very difficult when one example I see implementing something I have works, and what I have has the audacity of not listening to me. This is basically my Composable function, where I have a Scaffold, a Column that holds an Image and a Surface which is basically the Registration form. Now if you look at the image, android has a space for gesture navigation, that is solely for the purpose of interpreting the gesture for the system to manage. I enabled edge-to-edge in the activity class, i have the activity attribute of softInputMode set to "adjustResize" and I can't seem to find why that space is being drawn out, I removed every .imePadding() from all modifiers, yet that space is still there. I may be dumb and not see a solution and I'm hoping someone shines light on my dumb brain.
The space from gesture
@Composable
fun RegisterScreen(
    viewModel: RegisterCredentialsViewModel
){
    Shapes.setStatusBar()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val isEnabledInternet by viewModel.isEnabledInternet.observeAsState(null)
    val isEnabledRegister by viewModel.isEnabledRegister.observeAsState(null)
    val registerResult by viewModel.registerFormResult.observeAsState(null)

    LaunchedEffect(registerResult) {
        registerResult?.let {
            if (it.show) {  // Only show Snackbar for error messages
                snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = it.message,
                    withDismissAction = registerResult!!.withDismissAction,
                    duration = registerResult!!.duration
                )
                it.show = false
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        containerColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(
                hostState = snackbarHostState
            ) { data ->
                Snackbar(
                    snackbarData = data,
                    containerColor = registerResult!!.color
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(it)){
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(
                    when (isEnabledInternet!!) {
                        true -> R.drawable.img_signup_art
                        else -> R.drawable.no_internet
                    }
                ),
                contentDescription = "Register greet art",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(all = 15.dp)
                    .weight(.3f)
            )
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                    topStart = 25.dp,
                    topEnd = 25.dp
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .weight(.7f)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
//                        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
//                        .imePadding()
                        .padding(horizontal = 25.dp)
                        .padding(top = 25.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 10.dp),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        var user by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                        var pass by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                        var repass by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                        var email by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
                        val acceptedRegex = Regex("[\\w*.,<>?!'\"\\|/-=+@#$%^&()\\[\\]{}]*")
                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = user,
                            onValueChange = { newText ->
                                run {
                                    if (newText.matches(acceptedRegex) && newText.length <= 32) {
                                        user = newText
                                        viewModel.updateField(
                                            CredentialsField.USERNAME,
                                            user
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            placeholder = { Text("...", color = Color(0x55002200)) },
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp
                            ),
                            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.formRegisterUsername)) },
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Ascii,
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                            ),
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                                focusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                unfocusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedIndicatorColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
                            ),
                            singleLine = true
                        )
                        TextFieldSupportMaxLength(
                            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            textFieldValue = user,
                            maxLength = 32
                        )

                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = pass,
                            onValueChange = { newText ->
                                run {
                                    if (newText.matches(acceptedRegex) && newText.length <= 32) {
                                        pass = newText
                                        viewModel.updateField(
                                            CredentialsField.PASSWORD,
                                            pass
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            placeholder = { Text("***", color = Color(0x55002200)) },
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp
                            ),
                            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.formRegisterPassword)) },
                            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                            ),
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                                focusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                unfocusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedIndicatorColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
                            ),
                            singleLine = true
                        )

                        TextFieldSupportMaxLength(
                            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            textFieldValue = pass,
                            maxLength = 32
                        )

                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = repass,
                            onValueChange = { newText ->
                                run {
                                    if (newText.matches(acceptedRegex) && newText.length <= 32) {
                                        repass = newText
                                        viewModel.updateField(
                                            CredentialsField.REPASSWORD,
                                            repass
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            placeholder = { Text("***", color = Color(0x55002200)) },
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp
                            ),
                            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.formRegisterRepeatPassword)) },
                            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                            ),
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                                focusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                unfocusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedIndicatorColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
                            ),
                            singleLine = true
                        )
                        TextFieldSupportMaxLength(
                            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            textFieldValue = repass,
                            maxLength = 32
                        )
                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            value = email,
                            onValueChange = { newText ->
                                run {
                                    if (newText.matches(acceptedRegex) && newText.length <= 128) {
                                        email = newText
                                        viewModel.updateField(CredentialsField.EMAIL, email)
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            placeholder = { Text("***@***.com", color = Color(0x55002200)) },
                            textStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp
                            ),
                            label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.formRegisterEmail)) },
                            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
                            ),
                            colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                                focusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                unfocusedLabelColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedIndicatorColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
                            ),
                            singleLine = true
                        )
                        TextFieldSupportMaxLength(
                            Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(bottom = 15.dp),
                            textFieldValue = email,
                            maxLength = 128
                        )
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                run {
                                    viewModel.registerClick()
                                }
                            },
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            enabled = isEnabledRegister!!,
                            colors = ButtonColors(
                                containerColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                contentColor = hearty_theme_light_onPrimary,
                                disabledContainerColor = hearty_theme_light_primary.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                                disabledContentColor = hearty_theme_light_onPrimary.copy(alpha = 0.5f)
                            ),
                            contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 15.dp),
                            content = {
                                Text(
                                    text = stringResource(R.string.buttonRegister).uppercase(),
                                    color = Color.White,
                                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold
                                )
                            })
                    }
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(top = 15.dp, bottom = 15.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.formRegisterToLogin),
                            color = Color.Black,
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal
                        )

                        TextButton(
                            onClick = { viewModel.isReadyForLoginActivity.value = true },
                            contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp),
                            enabled = isEnabledRegister!!,
                            content = {
                                Text(
                                    text = stringResource(R.string.buttonLogin).uppercase(),
                                    color = hearty_theme_light_primary,
                                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried adding stuff like .imePadding() to every composable piece, Column, Surface, but to no avail. It added more space, on top of the already existing one, and I think I'm going insane.

Because you apply the inset provided by Scaffold to your composable. It adds padding to the top and bottom of your composable content.
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    containerColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackbarHostState
        ) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData = data,
                containerColor = registerResult!!.color
            )
        }
    }
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)){} // HERE !!!!
}

If you want to control which side you want to apply the inset to, you can apply it only to a specific side by using the named parameter of the padding modifier (top, bottom, ...)
Here is an example where i apply the insets only to the top, so the bottom padding you see will be removed:
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    containerColor = hearty_theme_light_primary,
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(
            hostState = snackbarHostState
        ) { data ->
            Snackbar(
                snackbarData = data,
                containerColor = registerResult!!.color
            )
        }
    }
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = it.calculateTopPadding())){}
}

